# PHP class fields are the same

Tags: php

I have a problem with PHP code.

Here is it:

```
class Note {
    public $title = "";
    public $text = "";
}

$note = new Note();
while($note_result = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $note->$title = $note_result["title"];
    $note->$text = $note_result["text"];
}
```

The problem is that `$note->$title` and `$note->$text` have the same value. I tried assigning `$note_result["..."]` to two different variables and it worked, but I would like to use class to return variable as one.

Am I missing something? I been checking this code for half an hour and found nothing.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: `$note->title` not `$note->$title` Expression like `$note->$title` will change the property name not value

Comment: Thank you, that worked.